# Better way to add extra attributes in RBAC (Role Based Access Control) tables?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, database-normalization, erd

I have implemented RBAC (Role Based Access Control) tables. I have a requirement to add extra attribute on some roles, like `2nd_pwd` attribute in `Admin` role, `address` attribute in `Customer` role.

I have done this design, but it violates data integrity. When you removed (let's say) `Admin` role, you also need to remove admin data from `Admin` table. So I decided to add trigger for this job.

Question:

1. Is there a design for this requirement without trigger but still doesn't violate data integrity?
2. What is the common implementation for this requirement? Is it normalized enough?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add extra attributes on RBAC's group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617688/how-to-add-extra-attributes-on-rbacs-group)

Comment: In Admin & Customer add (user,role) as PK & CASCADES FK to User_Role.